# Parse last imap login time from /var/log/mail.log

Tags: perl, logging

I've currently got a bash script that parses /var/log/mail.log to determine the last login time/date of a imap user. I've determined Perl is going to be a lot more efficient and quicker for this task, especially as the logs grow.

Given the following example /var/log/mail.log file:

```
Jul  5 06:57:54 mail-04 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user@foobar.com.au>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.x.x, lip=192.168.x.x
Jul  5 06:59:54 mail-04 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user@foobar.com.au>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.x.x, lip=192.168.x.x
Jul  5 06:59:59 mail-04 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<otheruser@foobar.com.au>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.x.x, lip=192.168.x.x
Jul  5 07:01:54 mail-04 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<user@foobar.com.au>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.x.x, lip=192.168.x.x
Jul  5 07:01:59 mail-04 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<otheruser@foobar.com.au>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.x.x, lip=192.168.x.x
```

What is the most efficient way in Perl to print the last login time of each unique user? E.g. the expected output should be:

```
user@foobar.com.au last imap-login: Jul 5 07:01:54
otheruser@foobar.com.au last imap-login: Jul 5 07:01:59
```

Comment: You keep saying "efficient".  What do you mean?  Do you have some specific speed requirements?  Memory requirements?  It makes no sense to worry about "efficiency" without specific requirements.

Comment: Currently I have a bash script running every 2 minutes to update a DB (to provide access to mangers to see when a staff member last logged in), this is all running on a dedicated syslog system but I am now in the process of focusing on revamping my parser scripts purely for efficiently as I expect the amount of imap users to grow exponentially. What I am after is lowering CPU time spent on parsing. Loading the complete file into memory is acceptable as the log file will be rotated every few days and isn't expected to grow more then a hundred of so megabyte (and memory is cheap).

Comment: To build on Andy Lester's comment, I would suggest that you postpone worries about efficiency. Get it working first, then speed it up, but only if necessary (simply switching from a shell script to Perl might provide the required performance boost). In general, you will need a line-by-line text processing loop (no need to store the whole file in memory), a simple regular expression (to snag the user name and login time), and a hash with the user name as the key and the last login as the value. If you hit any roadblocks while writing this script, StackOverflow will be a great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne '$l{$2}=$1 if /^(.{15}) .* imap-login: Login: user=<([^>]+)>/; END { print "$_ last imap-login: $l{$_}\n" for keys %l }' /var/log/mail.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a hash and keep assigning the login time to the user name sounds like a simple solution.

```
$logins{$username} = $date
```